# Font list not refreshing in apps in debian

Tags: debian, fonts

I copied a bunch of .ttf and otf fonts into ~/.fonts, made sure permissions where set to my user/group and ran `fc-cache ~/.fonts`.

Opened up GIMP and Geany but the fonts aren't available. Any idea what's up?

Comment: post the contents of `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` or `/etc/fonts/local.conf`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xMhTCL2D (no local.conf)

Comment: Try `fc-cache -fv` and see if its actually scanning `~/.fonts`, and see how many fonts it finds. You may also get lucky and find that `-f` fixes it...

Comment: ~/.fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs

Comment: also, they appear to be under ./.fontconfig too but still not showing inside any apps?

Comment: @user1561108 Well, that '0 fonts, 0 dirs' is the problem. Something isn't right about the font files. Check `ls -l ~/.fonts/` to make sure they're there; also maybe `file` on each one to confirm the format.

Comment: I added them to .gimp/fonts and they've appeared in gimp so have a temporary workaround at least

Comment: Execute `fc-cache --verbose`. Check for any complains about invalid files in ~/.fonts or in ~/.fontconfig.

Comment: running fc-cache as root seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @user1561108 Sounds like you have a permissions problem somewhere. You shouldn't need to run it as root for things in `~/.fonts` (and indeed, I don't on any of my machines).

Answer (score 0):

I've used to face same problem but I've solved adding another folder instead of use the default gimp's .... Have you reviewed the GIMP's folders configuration ? Also you can add folder for example in your /home/user1561108/myFavFonts

[image]